# JAVA SOAP webservice converting empty ArrayList to null

Tags: java, web-services, soap, arraylist

I have a SOAP WebService operation which returns an object that has an ArrayList as a member variable. The WS client calls the operation and does things with the returned object.

I have noticed that if that ArrayList is empty (not null) in the WebService, when it reaches the client, it becomes null. I also noticed that the client class (auto-generated by WSIMPORT) has a getter for the ArrayList which has a null check in it. If the ArrayList is null, the getter returns a new empty ArrayList.

This tells me that somehow during the transfer of the object from WebService to the client in SOAP packet, an empty ArrayList is getting converted to null. And that's why wsimport adds that special null check in getter.

Is my suspicion correct? Is this expected behavior? Please let me know if my question is not clear enough.

Comment: Is there a specific problem here, or are you just wondering? It would help to have some example. Your suspicion is correct, it's based on how JAXB operates... but why are you asking? What is the problem?

Comment: As long as I use the getter to get the ArrayList from inside the returned object, I am good. The reason I noticed the null-ness is because I was doing a Dozer mapping to a different class, using is-accessible=true, which uses Reflection to map the fields directly without getter. I switched the dozer mapping to use getter and things are fine.

Any idea why JAXB turns an empty collection into a null over the network?